# Assign value to EditorFor using javascript

Tags: javascript, editorfor

I have this code in my view :

```
    <div class="drop-down-list">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.StageId,new { id="hiddenStageID"}) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StageId) %>
    </div>
```

And this is my javascript code to set value of EditorFor. But it does not work :

```
<script>
           var e = document.getElementById("stageTwoView");
           var listIndex = e.selectedIndex;
           var stageIdVal = list[listIndex].valueOf();
           document.getElementById('hiddenStageID').value = stageIdVal;
</script>
```

for example stageIdVal get this value : "1003". But the last line does not work! Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditorFor` doesn't accept `htmlAttributes` as a parameter (which is what I think you're anticipating); that would be `TextBoxFor`.

What you're doing is passing `additionalViewData` to the editor template, so unless you're using that in your EditorTemplate, you won't actually be assigning an ID to the element (and therefore can't retrieve it with JS).

If you wanted to give the text field an ID, either customize your editor template, or use `TextBoxFor` instead so you *can* pass it additional attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxfor(x => x.StageId, new { id = "hiddenStageID" })
```

Unless I'm wrong (which I may be because I don't have the template visible in front of me. You may have customized it, in which case I'm just making an inaccurate assumption and I can update my answer).

Comment: No problem. Remember to not take the razor parser for granted; always view-source to make sure the element you're trying to output and the actual output align. ;-)